# What I have this rare output value of variance and standart deviation functions in numpy?

Tags: python, variance, mean, standard-deviation, numpy

Hell i have nonsense values of variance and standart deviation in numpy.

this documentation no make sense with this sample.
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html

[image]

youtube example calculation mean:9, var:9

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([6,9,14,10,5,8,1])
>>> np.mean(a)
7.571428571428571
>>> np.var(a)
14.530612244897958
>>> np.std(a)
3.8119040183218096
>>> np.nanvar(a)
14.530612244897958
```

edit for youtubeissues:

```
a=np.array([5,6,8,9,10,11,14]) 
>>> np.var(a) 8.0
```

edit for a smaller sample for apply the variance equation
a=2,3,4,5 mean=3.5

var=((2-3.5)**2+(2-3.5)**2+(3-3.5)**2+(4-3.5)**2+(5-3.5)**2) / 3
= 2.4166666666666665

```
>>> a=np.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> np.var(a)
1.25
>>> np.mean(a)
3.5
>>> np.std(a)
1.118033988749895
```

How i fix this value of variance?
what is the problem with numpy?

Comment: Because they're using the "Data" column from the table on the left with data points {5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14}.

Comment: >>> a=np.array([5,6,8,9,10,11,14])
>>> np.var(a)
8.0

i can make smaller:
2,3,4,5.mean=3.5.std=((2-3.5)**2+(2-3.5)**2+(3-3.5)**2+(4-3.5)**2+(5-3.5)**2) / 3 = 2.4166666666666665

>>> a=np.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> np.var(a)
1.25. you see it?

Comment: Numpy uses the biased formula for standard deviation and variance by default instead of the unbiased one using Bessel's correction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600207/why-does-numpy-std-give-a-different-result-to-matlab-std

Comment: See this as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @whuber is not variance different deffinitions take a look this:
>>> ((2-3.5)**2+(2-3.5)**2+(3-3.5)**2+(4-3.5)**2+(5-3.5)**2)/4
=1.8125
can you open again the question? for i answer my own queston and giving all the credit to Eric Perkerson for the help!.

Comment: @EricPerkerson
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array([2,3,4,5])
>>> np.std(a, ddof=3)
2.23606797749979
still nothing oh my god why

Comment: >>> a = np.array([5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14]); >>> np.var(a, ddof=1) = 9.3333333333333339, as in their example. Use 1 degree of freedom for the corrected formula, not 3.